# How to update core data value in a UITableView cell textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm setting up a very basic feature of an app, something like a todo list/ notepad, where users would add a blank cell to a UITableView. The cell would contain the system time when the note line was created and can enter their note into a textField.

I have managed to set up the app up to adding a blank cell with the static system time and holding text in the textField however, after lots of searching I just can't figure out how to save/ make persistent the textFields value after the user finished editing or adds a new note cell.

I have tried to reverse the way in which I added the cells to the persistent container however this wouldn't say to the app which cell it's updating just create a new one.

I'm not allowed to post a picture yet so here is my description: 
It's a UITableView with a bar button "Add" on the right side and a cell containing a UIlabel containing (systemTime) on the left and a textField (noteLine) filling the right of the cell.

```
|--------------------------------------|
|                 notepad            + |
|--------------------------------------|
|Prototype cell                        |
|--------------------------------------|
|12:17:12 |***textField***            ||
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|                                      |
|______________________________________|
```

---

My Vars are:

```
    var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    var pc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Here is my code adding a new "note line"

```
func newNoteline() {
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: pc)

        let item = Entity(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: pc)

        item.notesheetLine = "Test"
        item.timenoteline = timeOutlet.text

        do {

            try pc.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

From this, I have tried the following to save but it does not work - I'm guessing because I'm not telling the app what cell to update.

```
    func save() {

            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: pc)

            let item = Entity(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: pc)

            item.notesheetLine = "Test Save"


        do {

            try pc.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I have also tried this but yet again no luck:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        let noteline = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notelineIdentifier", for: indexPath!) as! notesheetTableViewCell

        let item = frc.object(at: indexPath!) as! Entity

        item.timeLine = noteline.timeLineOutlet.text

        do {

            try pc.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }
```

Currently, I can create a new cell line that contains the right time. It is persistent when the app is restarted but when I edit the cell value it clears as soon as I deselect the cell or create a new cell line.

So could someone put me out my misery and tell me what/if there is a function that would let a user select a textField within a cell, edit it and once the user has finished editing it would update the coreData value with the textField value.

Comment: Can you show the code in `cellForRowAt:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` objects are reference type, a suitable solution is to pass the entity item to the cell

- In `NotesheetTableViewCell` (please name it with a starting capital letter) add a property

  ```
  var entity : Entity!
  ```
- In `cellForRowAt` pass the model item to the cell

  ```
  let item = frc.object(at: indexPath) as! Entity
  cell.entity = item
  ```
- In `NotesheetTableViewCell` add the `textDidEndEditing` delegate method, when it's called update `entity`.
- In  `didEndEditingRowAt` save the context.